# Changing the default value of Bug work item 's summary field to contain the steps to reproduce

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS 2012 update 1 with VS 2012

When we create a new bug from the failed test case, i want the summary field to contain both the steps of a linked test case and the parameters table from it (we want to allow users to see al the information in the summary window without forcing them to open a linked work item and moving between them).

I do not need to use Web API, but i would like it to work both from MTM and VS.

Any ideas? Is this available out of the box or do i have to make some customizations, and if so where i can read on that API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply relate your bug work item to your test case work item by **link**.
 Why don't you use that? and did you go over any **TFS object model**?

Comment: Because the requirement is to show it in the first tab without forcing the user to go to the link,and open linked item in another form.